# convert dec number to 6 bit binary number

Tags: python, binary, bin

I am looking to convert a dec number to a 6 bit binary number.. `bin()` works fine but omits leading zeros which are important.

for example:

- 0 = 000000
- 1 = 000001
- 2 = 000010

etc... with the largest dec number allowed being 63.

Comment: Just use `bin()` and [left-pad the result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/python-nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either what Matt said in the comment (`bin(63)[2:].zfill(6)`), or use [format strings](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) in Python 2.6+:

```
'{0:06b}'.format(63)
```

You can omit the first zero in Python 2.7+ as you can implicitly number groups.

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
n2=[2**x for x in xrange(0, 7)]
n2.reverse()

def getx(x):
    ret = ''
    for z in n2:
        if x >= z:
            x -= z
            ret += '1'
        else:
            ret += '0'

    return ret
```