# Error in converting array with decimals into array with binaries in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to covert and array filed with decimals from 0 to 63 , x=[0 1 2 ... 63] into an array with the equal binaries, but I get the following error:
"invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b0'". My code is the following (in Python) :

```
g=np.arange(0,64,1)
for x in range(0,64,1):
    g[x]=bin(g[x])
```

I am new to python, so if anyone can find my mistake (logic or syntax) I would appreciate any help. **extra**: Is there any way to make the binaries 6 bits that get put in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python 3:
 Initialize the g array first, then append it in the loop.

```
g = '{0:06b}'.format(0)

for x in range(1,64,1):
    g=np.append(g,'{0:06b}'.format(x))

print(g)
```

**extra:** Python is very well [documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687928/convert-dec-number-to-6-bit-binary-number)

hth

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store them as strings representing binary numbers.

```
>>> x=0x1011   # hex
>>> x
4113           #just another number under the hood
>>> x=0b1011
>>> x
11
>>> x=str(0b1011)
>>> x
'11'
>>> x=str(bin(11))
>>> x
'0b1011'
>>>

bin_list = []
for each in range(64):
    bin_rep = str(bin(each))
    bin_rep = bin_rep[:2] + bin_rep[2:].zfill(6)
    bin_list.append(bin_rep)

print(bin_list)
```

Not as concise as another comment but possibly more easy to follow for someone new to Python... Hope this helps!