# Generate output without losing leading zeroes

Tags: python, sage

I am using sage maths (which uses Python(more or less)) to do some work involving cryptography. This involves using binary keys which you xor to generate a cipher or message.
Often, the input data is nn hex and so I have to convert to binary to see what is going on.
Here is an example of the kind of thing I am doing once I have my binary.

```
my_cip=0b01101.....
my_mes=0b0110....
ot_mes=0b011...
my_key=0b0000....
key_fn=0b00....
altcip=0b011011..
print my_key.__xor__(ot_mes).binary()
```

The problem is that when I use utility functions to convert ascii to binary and hex to binary, the result has any leading zeroes thrown away.

I do not know how many have been thrown away so I have been predicting how many bits should be in the result and sticking the appropriate number of zeroes on the front of the result.

**Here is my question!**
Is there a way of forcing the leading zeroes to be included in the result of calling (for example) ?

```
`print Integer(0x6c73.....).binary() ?`
```

Comment: See <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/python-nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string">here</a> how you pad zeroes nicely.

Comment: If you post that as an answer I will credit it with a tick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/python-nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string). It shows you how to pad zeroes very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

*Use format()*

See documentation [Python format documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. zmbq drilled down to the specific answer that I was after which is a subset of format.