# how print in form horizontal in python

Tags: python

Hi my program print on this way:

Mesagge to binary:asd

```
01100001
01110011
01100100
```

but i need to print the message in form horizontal like this (011000010111001101100100)

Ive been trying everything i don know how to do it.

```
def string_a_binario(s):

    for i in range (0, len(s)):

        if s[i] == " " : 
            print("00100001")
        elif s[i] == "!" :
            print("00100001")

        elif s[i] == "#" :
            print("00100011")
        elif s[i] == "$" :
            print("00100100")
        elif s[i] == "%" :
            print("00100101")
        elif s[i] == "&" :
            print("00100110")
        elif s[i] == "'" :
            print("00100111")
        elif s[i] == "(" :
            print("00101000")
        elif s[i] == ")" :
            print("00101001")
        elif s[i] == "*" :
            print("00101010")
        elif s[i] == "+" :
            print("00101011")
        elif s[i] == "," :
            print("00101100")
        elif s[i] == "-" :
            print("00101101")
        elif s[i] == "." :
            print("00101110")
        elif s[i] == "/" :
            print("00101111")
        elif s[i] == "0" :
            print("00110000")
        elif s[i] == "1" :
            print("00110001")
        elif s[i] == "2" :
            print("00110010")
        elif s[i] == "3" :
            print("00110011")
        elif s[i] == "4" :
            print("00110100")
        elif s[i] == "5" :
            print("00110101")
        elif s[i] == "6" :
            print("00110110")
        elif s[i] == "7" :
            print("00110111")
        elif s[i] == "8" :
            print("00111000")
        elif s[i] == "9" :
            print("00111001")
        elif s[i] == ":" :
            print("00111010")
        elif s[i] == ";" :
            print("00111011")
        elif s[i] == "<" :
            print("00111100")
        elif s[i] == "=" :
            print("00111101")
        elif s[i] == ">" :
            print("00111110")
        elif s[i] == "?" :
            print("00111111")
        elif s[i] == "@" :
            print("01000000")
        elif s[i] == "A" :

            print("01000001")
        elif s[i] == "B" :
            print("01000010")

        elif s[i] == "C" :
            print("01000011")

        elif s[i] == "D" :
            print("01000100")
        elif s[i] == "E" :
            print("01000101")
        elif s[i] == "F" :
            print("01000110")
        elif s[i] == "G" :
            print("01000111")
        elif s[i] == "H" :
            print("01001000")
        elif s[i] == "I" :
            print("01001001")
        elif s[i] == "J" :
            print("01001010")
        elif s[i] == "K" :
            print("01001011")
        elif s[i] == "L" :
            print("01001100")
        elif s[i] == "M" :
            print("01001101")
        elif s[i] == "Ñ" :
            print("01001110")
        elif s[i] == "O" :
            print("01001111")
        elif s[i] == "P" :
            print("01010000")
        elif s[i] == "Q" :
            print("01010001")
        elif s[i] == "R" :
            print("01010010")
        elif s[i] == "O" :
            print("01001111")
        elif s[i] == "P" :
            print("01010000")
        elif s[i] == "Q" :
            print("01010001")
        elif s[i] == "R" :
            print("01010010")
        elif s[i] == "S" :
            print("01010011")

        elif s[i] == "T" :
            print("01010100")
        elif s[i] == "U" :
            print("01010101")
        elif s[i] == "V" :
            print("01010110")
        elif s[i] == "W" :
            print("01010111")
        elif s[i] == "X" :
            print("01011000")
        elif s[i] == "Y" :
            print("01011001")
        elif s[i] == "Z" :
            print("01011010")

        elif s[i] == "[" :
            print("01011011")
        elif s[i] == " \ "  :
            print("01011100")
        elif s[i] == "]" :
            print("01011101")
        elif s[i] == "^" :
            print("01011110")
        elif s[i] == "_" :
            print("01011111")
        elif s[i] == "`" :
            print("01100000")


        elif s[i] == "a" :
            print("01100001")
        elif s[i] == "b" :
            print("01100010")
        elif s[i] == "c" :
            print("01100011")
        elif s[i] == "d" :
            print("01100100")
        elif s[i] == "e" :
            print("01100101")
        elif s[i] == "f" :
            print("01100110")
        elif s[i] == "g" :
            print("01100111")
        elif s[i] == "h" :
            print("01101000")
        elif s[i] == "i" :
            print("01101001")
        elif s[i] == "j" :
            print("01101010")
        elif s[i] == "k" :
            print("01101011")
        elif s[i] == "l" :
            print("01101100")
        elif s[i] == "m" :
            print("01101101")
        elif s[i] == "n" :
            print("01101110")
        elif s[i] == "o" :
            print("01101111")
        elif s[i] == "p" :
            print("01110000")
        elif s[i] == "q" :
            print("01110001")
        elif s[i] == "r" :
            print("01110010")
        elif s[i] == "s" :
            print("01110011")
        elif s[i] == "t" :
            print("01110100")
        elif s[i] == "u" :
            print("01110101")
        elif s[i] == "v" :
            print("01110110")
        elif s[i] == "w" :
            print("01110111")
        elif s[i] == "x" :
            print("01111000")
        elif s[i] == "y" :
            print("01111001")
        elif s[i] == "z" :
            print("01111010")
        elif s[i] == "{" :
            print("01111011")
        elif s[i] == "|" :
            print("01111100")
        elif s[i] == "}" :
            print("01111101")
        elif s[i] == "~" :
            print("01111110")

s = list(input("Message to binary:"))
string_a_binario(s)
```

Comment: \`backticks\` are for `in-line code`. Indent by four spaces for blocks of code.

Comment: too many if statements

Comment: @Mai Agreed. Just because his code is poor, doesn't mean he's not trying.

Comment: Guys do you know a way to write my code in the correct way because my code can transform a message in binary but when i print for every character my code print the binary code like

Comment: [01010101]                                                                   [10101010]                                                               ...                                                                      and i need to write inthis way:[0101010110101010.....] do you understand?

Answer (score 3):

As for the multiple lines issue, if you put a comma (`,`) at the end of a `print` statement, it will not print a newline character:

Example:

```
print 'Put these on',
print 'just one line',
print 'please'
```

Prints:

```
Put these on just one line please
```

Note: This still prints spaces after each item. If that is unacceptable, use `sys.stdout.write()` like [Mai showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19470270/119527).

---

There is a ***much*** better way to accomplish this than hard-coding every case! (I can't imagine how long it took you to write that!)

Hints:

- [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) converts a character to its integer value
- [`bin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) formats an integer as binary string
- [Nicest way to pad zeroes to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/python-nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string)

Other python hints:

- There's no need to convert the result of `input` to a `list` - strings in python are iterable.
- This isn't C - you don't need to iterate with an array index. Instead you can iterate over each *item* in the sequence. Here, those items are each character of the string!

```
for i in range (0, len(s)):
    if s[i] == " " :
       ...
```

Can be replaced with

```
for x in s:
    is x == " ":
        ...
```

Comment: @Leonardo I'm not sure. I believe `print` is a function now, so it may not - I'd have to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Say I have two string `s1` and `s2`:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(s1)
sys.stdout.write(s2)
sys.stdout.write('\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Then s1 and s2 will be printed in the same line.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Whatis s1 and s2 i dont know could you write it

Comment: @Felipe He just said: "Say I have two strings `s1` and `s2`"

Answer (score 0):

I just want to address how you wrote your function, it may introduce some error. For example, look at the first two `if` statements in your loop, it looks like the space and `!` characters both output `00100001`, was that desired? Here is something that is sort of similar to your function, and potentially takes out some human error.

```
def string_a_binario(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        sys.stdout.write("{0:08b}".format(ord(s[i])))
```

This code also writes horizontally as you desired. But, it does not do the same thing as your function for all input. For example your code prints nothing if none of the conditions are ever met, while this function could print something where yours could not.

In python 3 (and maybe previous versions, I am not for sure) you can tell print not to include the newline, here is another version of the function:

```
def string_a_binario(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print("{0:08b}".format(ord(s[i])), end='')
```

Here is yet another version in python 3 which puts a bracket around each binary representation:

```
def string_a_binario(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        print("[{0:08b}".format(ord(s[i])), end=']')
```