# Format number in python with leading zeros and fixed decimal places

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to format a number into a string in python. The result I hope for is for `0.1423` to be converted to `000.14`. I tried

```
num = 0.1423
print '%0.2f' %num
```

But this just results in the `0.14`. I can't seem to get the leading zeros.

Cheers,
James

Comment: Are you trying to make a method that does this for any `float x`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
num = 0.1423
print '%06.2f' %num
```

The six indicates the total field width and includes the decimal point. The zero indicates include leading zeros, the 2 indicates the precision.

Answer (score 2):

The field width has to be provided as well to get the required number of leading zeros:

```
print "%06.2f" % num
```

Output:

```
000.14
```

Answer (score 2):

use  [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
 print "{:06.2f}".format(num)
```