# Mencoder generates a video that uses first figure multiple times

Tags: mencoder

I generate png figures using python and then use mencoder to make a movie. I used the commend I searched online. It does generate a movie for me. But it's strange that it uses the first figure multiple times during the entire movie. That is not what I want. I'm not sure why. The code is below:

```
os.system("mencoder 'mf://_tmp*.png' -mf type=png:fps=10.0 -ovc vcodec=wmv2 -oac copy -o " + filename + ".mpg")
```

Comment: How are your files named? Is the first frame `_tmp1.png` or `_tmp00001.png`? If the former, try to pad all your frame numbers to a fixed length and see if that fixes it.

Comment: they are named as _tmp100.png, _tmp200.png and so on.

Comment: OK, and is `_tmp900.png` followed by `_tmp1000.png`?

Comment: Thank you very much. That fixed it.

Comment: No problem. If my answer solved your problem, please do consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark icon on its left side.

Comment: no problem. Clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I suspect that mencoder is sorting your frames by their filename, *as strings*.  That is, the sort order will start like this:

```
_tmp1.png
_tmp10.png
_tmp100.png
_tmp101.png
_tmp102.png
...
_tmp109.png
_tmp11.png
_tmp110.png
_tmp111.png
_tmp112.png
...
```

<sup>(In the comments you say that your filenames actually look like `_tmp100.png`, `_tmp200.png`, etc., but the extra trailing zeros should make no difference.)</sup>

Obviously, this will cause every tenth frame in your final video to be misordered.

If this is the problem, [zero-padding the frame numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string) in your file names to a fixed length should fix it.