# How do I check presence of web pages by making changes to a URL, please see details?

Tags: javascript, python, curl, web, urllib

If we have a URL :

```
https://www.example.com/123.html
```

I wish to check if other web pages are present by changing certain portion of URL , in this case we can do by changing numbers.

Hence :

```
https://www.example.com/124.html
```

So how can i do it , say run a script , which checks presence of web pages in this directory by changing , in this case , last three numbers , say from 000 to 999 ?

Comment: What code have you tried? You should have a look at Python's `range` function along with a `for` loop if you want to "trial-and-error" different URLs.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 Thanks for replying buddy , yes thats exactly what i want , a "trial and error" , i will try using python  range function , but just a offf question here DO we have any libraries that can do this by just inputting the URL and feeding them the ranges.?

Comment: It's not a Python library, rather a program, but this is the sort of thing that [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp/) is for.

Answer (score 0):

For formatting the number, you can use `format` along with a format string in later versions of Python (>=2.7?) or `x.zfill(3)` in earlier versions. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string).

For making requests in a loop:

```
import requests

for x in range(1000):
   page = requests.get('https://www.example.com/{0:03d}.html'.format(X))
   print(page.content)
```