# Python: renaming files returns the wrong name

Tags: python, csv, directory, renaming

Say I have a folder with 1000 csv files which names are `event_1.csv`, `event_2.csv`,..., `event_1000.csv`.

I in fact have 25 folders like this and want to rename those files in such a way that the first 4 characters are `0001` for the first folder, `0002` for the second, all the way up to `0025`. The last 4 characters represent the event, such that the 1st event is `0001`, the second `0002`, all the way to `1000`.

So the 1st file in the 1st folder is changed in this fashion: `event_1.csv = 00010001.csv`.

Anyway my code is wrong, in that the first 100 files in the 1st folder are named `00020000.csv` to `00020099.csv`, since `0002` should be used in the 2nd folder only. Then, from the 101st file to the last, I get the correct filenames: `00010101.csv` to `00011000.csv`.

**This is my code: what is wrong with that?**

```
import os, sys
import glob
import csv

directory=r'C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Tests'
subdir=[x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)]
subdir.pop(0)

N=['0001','0002','0003','0004','0005','0006','0007','0008','0009','0010','0011','0012','0013','0014','0015','0016','0017','0018','0019','0020','0021','0022','0023','0024','0025']

for i in subdir:
    for n in N:
        temp_dir=r''+i
        os.chdir(temp_dir)
        A=str(n)
        for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
            if len(file)==11:
                event='000'+str(file[6])
                newname=A+event
                os.rename(file, newname + '.csv')
            if len(file)==12:
                event='00'+str(file[6:8])
                newname=A+event
                os.rename(file, newname + '.csv')
            if len(file)==13:
                event='0'+str(file[6:9])
                newname=A+event
                os.rename(file, newname + '.csv')
            if len(file)==14:
                event=file[6:10]
                newname=A+event
                os.rename(file, newname + '.csv')
```

Comment: You might want to look into [zero-padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string) to simplify your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure about all the names of your files, you could considerably simplify your code (as M.T said). Try maybe something like :

```
for n,i in enumerate(subdir):
        os.chdir(r''+i)   # Or whatever your folders are named
        for m,file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
            newname = "{0:04d}{1:04d}.csv".format(n+1,m+1)
            os.rename(file, newname)
```

**EDIT : it's better with enumerate.**

Comment: `subdir` is the list of all the 25 folders, which are located in a mother folder.

Comment: This will ignore the current name of files and just rename in whatever order glob.glob() return them.

Comment: perhaps use `enumerate` instead of counters at the cost of writing `n+1` in `format`? and also `n++` is not python syntax, instead `n+=1`.

Comment: You're right, it seems "natural" that the files come in the lexical order but it is not certain... Do you have a trick to fix that ?

Comment: @Daneel one could parse the filenames. `m=int(filename[6:-4])`

Comment: IDK maybe regex to match the digit group and padding it.