# Print the following pattern in shortest no of characters

Tags: python

What can be the smallest possible code in any language(I guess Python will win) to print 
"001002003004005006007008009010011012013014015016017018019020021022023024025"

Basically it is counting from 1 to 25.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a tutorial/learning site. There is Google, for that

Comment: youre probably better off asking this question on code golf

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
print("".join(map(lambda x:str(x).zfill(3),range(1,26))))
```

or

```
print(reduce(lambda x,y:x+str(y).zfill(3),range(1,26),""))
```

Comment: Can we do better using regex?

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string) to pad the numbers with zero's after converting them to strings. Then simply join the strings together and print or print each string. But the first one should get the job done.

```
for i in range(1,26):
    print(str(n).zfill(3), end="")
```

Comment: Can we do better using regex?

Comment: I don't believe there'd be a "nice" way of doing it in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in python3

```
    [print("%03d"%i,end='') for i in range(1,26)]
```