# adding numbers to string representations of numbers in python

Tags: python, string, integer, data-conversion

I'm dealing with strings of the following form '000351'. Think of them as odometer readings. I want to increment them. For example
I want to add 1 to '000345' and get '000346'.

The following python code does the job, but appears rather cumbersome. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
s='000345'
t=int(s)
t=t+1
int_to_6digit_string(t)
```

where the function int_to_6digit_string() is as follows

```
def int_to_6digit_string(i):
    if i<0 or i>999999:
        return 'argument out of bounds'
    j=str(i)
    if len(j) == 1:
        return '00000'+j
    elif len(j) == 2:
        return '0000'+j
    elif len(j) == 3:
        return '000'+j
    elif len(j) == 4:
        return '00'+j
    elif len(j) == 5:
        return '0'+j
    else:
        return j
```

Comment: This would be better submitted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What should happen at overflow (`s` exactly 999999)? Have you considered using `str.format()` instead?

Comment: You could just use zfill() function.

Comment: [Lots of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string) to pad a number with 0.

Comment: including what i've answered

Answer (score 1):

use string format: `'{:06}'.format(your_number)`