# Python string formatting with 'n' number of digits (when using keys) Python 2.7

Tags: python, string-formatting

To have specific number of digits in string formatting, I am aware that it can be done in this way:

```
In [18]: hours = 01

In [19]: "%.2d" %(hours)
Out[19]: '01'

In [20]: "%.2f" %(hours)
Out[20]: '1.00'
```

But my case is a bit different. I am using specific keys to denote the values, for example:

```
for filename in os.listdir('/home/user/zphot_01/')
```

Here I want to have different values for the `'01'`, i.e.

```
for filename in os.listdir('/home/user/zphot_{value1}/'.format(value1=some_number):
```

**When I use the above method with `some_number = 01`, it does not take into account the `0` and so my folder is not recognised.**

**EDIT:**

Most of the answers are for only one value, however, I want to have more than one key value, i.e.:

```
for filename in os.listdir('/home/user/zphot_{value1}/zphot_{value2}'.format(value1=some_number1,value2=some_number2)).
```

Comment: Please use the new string formatting and you won't have a lot of these problems.

Comment: You can use `'1'.zfill(2)`

Comment: @user1767754: Could you please give me a link

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: '{value:02d}'.format(value=1)

Comment: Or you could upgrade to Python 3.6 and use f-strings, Eg `f'{value1:02}'`

Answer (score 3):

The [new format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) allows you to use format specifiers, just like the old `%`-based syntax. The format specifiers you can use are similar, not exactly the same in all cases (I think), but as far as I know, anything you could do with the old syntax can also be done with the new syntax.

All you have to do is put the format specifier inside the formatting expression, separated from the field name/number by a colon. In this case, you could use `{value1:02d}`, where `02d` is the code to get a zero-filled (`0`) width-2 (`2`) representation of an integer (`d`).

Comment: This is surely a more pythonic way than the other one.

Comment: How to go about in Python 2.7 ?

Comment: The new string format codes also work in Python 2.7.

Comment: @DavidZ: It doesn't! It still does not recognise the `0` in `01`

Comment: @ThePredator What is that `0` supposed to mean? Are you talking about when you set `hours = 01`? You should know that in code, `1` and `01` represent exactly the same value

Comment: This votes were 5-0 initially... how is it 3-2 now?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I dunno, I also found it odd and somewhat disappointing that the score on my answer dropped from 5 to 1 (now 2) and the votes on user1767754's answer went up from 0 to 2 (now 3) after their answer was edited to use the technique I suggested... but voters are fickle. Not much to do about it, I suppose, unless someone offers a reason for the downvote (and/or retracted upvotes) on my answer that is something I can fix.

Comment: @DavidZ: I have a folder named `zphot_01`, and another inside this folder named `zphot_02` and so on.. Now I want to specify `01` to be the first value and `02` to be second value as you can see `zphot_` is constant in both the folders. This was my question

Answer (score 1):

```
print("{0:02}".format(1))
>>0001
```

Just learnt from other answers and commentators that we don't need `zfill` but can use the expression `:02` to give the padding.

**Expand to more positions**:

```
print("{0:02}_{1:02}".format(1, 2))
>>0001_0002
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but don't you think `'/home/user/zphot_{}/'.format('1'.zfill(2))` is better?

Comment: I love grumpy downvoters

Comment: I was about to iteratively make my answer better

Comment: @user1767754: What if i have two or more key values ?

Comment: There's no need for a separate `.zfill` call: `.format` can do that operation. Eg, `"{0:02}".format(1)`

Comment: Do you want to combine them or something like `01_02`

Comment: @user1767754: not my downvote, so if it was you, then please!!

Comment: @user1767754: I want to have two or more key values, i.e. some_number2, some_number3 etc..

Comment: Just updated the answer, do you mean something like that?

Comment: Um, your answer is now a carbon copy of DavidZ's...

Comment: Well, what do you suggest to do? I personally first liked/used `zfill` but when `DavidZ` mentioned format strings nice filling methodology, i went with that. I would be stubborn not to do. I either delete the post or keep it.. his doesn't provide an example yet.

Comment: Still iterating, I'm not the downvoter.... but keep in mind that taking a solution someone else suggested first as yours is a little unfair to that other person.

Comment: Well you didn't answer my question :D

Answer (score 1):

## There are a lot of ways. Look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339013/7655838).

This is my subjetive opinion, but I have ordered them by worst to best.

```
>>> '1'.zfill(2)
'01'
>>> '%02d' % 1
'01'
>>> '%02s' % '1'
'01'
>>> '{0:0>2}'.format(1)
'01'
>>> '{0:02d}'.format(1)
'01'
>>> '{:02d}'.format(1)
'01'
>>> f'{1:02}'
'01'
```

Then, you have to combine that with your current string, nothing really complicate.

### Edit:

I am not sure what the OP is asking with his edit exactly but:

```
for filename in os.listdir('/home/user/zphot_{value1}/zphot_{value2}'.format(value1=some_number1,value2=some_number2)).
```

Can be changed by a lot of ways, I'll give some examples:

```
>>> number_first, number_second = '1', '2'
>>> '/home/user/zphot_{value1}/zphot_{value2}'.format(value1 = number_first.zfill(2), value2 = '2'.zfill(2))
'/home/user/zphot_01/zphot_02'
>>> '/home/user/zphot_{}/zphot_{}'.format('1'.zfill(2), number_second.zfill(2))
'/home/user/zphot_01/zphot_02'
>>> f'/home/user/zphot_{{number_first:02}}/zphot_{2:02}'
'/home/user/zphot_01/zphot_02'    
>>> '/home/user/zphot_%02d/zphot_%02s' % (1, '2')
'/home/user/zphot_01/zphot_02'
>>> '/home/user/zphot_{:02d}/zphot_{:02d}'.format(1, 2)
'/home/user/zphot_01/zphot_02'
```

Etc.

Comment: Lovely, thanks for the dupe target.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, my english isn't really good and the translator think you are going to kill someone with "dupe target"... but, you're welcome, I guess.

Comment: I want to use it for more than one value

Comment: @ThePredator, Could you explain better? I don't understand what are you meaning.

Comment: I have edited my question, please look

Comment: @ThePredator, better?