# concatenating strings creates an extra 0

Tags: python, loops, concatenation

im incrementing a counter that leads to an index of a list

code:

```
delist = []
i = 1
idx = [0, ..., 10, ..., 100, ..., 1000, ...]

while( i < len(idx)):

    if i in range(1, 10):
        delist.append("ladybug_cube_00000" + str(idx[i]) + "_0.jpg")

    elif i in range(10, 100):
        delist.append("ladybug_cube_0000" + str(idx[i]) + "_0.jpg")

    elif i in range(100, 1000):
        delist.append("ladybug_cube_000" + str(idx[i]) + "_0.jpg")

    elif i in range(1000, 10000):
        delist.append("ladybug_cube_00" + str(idx[i]) + "_0.jpg")

    elif i in range(10000, 100000):
        delist.append("ladybug_cube_0" + str(idx[i]) + "_0.jpg")

    elif i in range(100000, 1000000):
        delist.append("ladybug_cube_" + str(idx[i]) + "_0.jpg")

    #this deletes that index from the list
    del idx[i]

    #this goes an step back so it repeats the loop with the new index's variable.
    i = i-1
i= i+1
```

The issue is that it should store every string into a new index in the list "delist" and every element should have exacly 6 digits after "cube_" and before "_0.jpg", but it is storing an extra 0 before "str(idx[i])".

example output:

```
delist=["ladybug_cube_000001_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_000010_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_000100_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_001000_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_010000_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_100000_0.jpg"]
```

What I'm getting:

```
delist=["ladybug_cube_000001_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_0000010_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_00000100_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_000001000_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_0000010000_0.jpg", "ladybug_cube_00000100000_0.jpg"]
```

like it won't pass from "range(1, 10)".

Comment: You can pad your string with zeros to the desired length: https://stackoverflow.com/a/339013/8881141 Use simply `"ladybug_" + str(i).zfill(7) + "_0.jpg"`.

Comment: Something in the indentation might have gone wrong when you posted. Should i=i+1 be inside the loop? If yes, then i doesn't really change, and is always in range(1,10). As MrT has already noted, thee are simpler ways to pad with zeroes. Also, there probably are simpler was to iterate over a list.

Comment: @Sebastian indentation is ok, I tried swaping conditions order and it always takes range(1,10).
i always increments, it only repeats itself if it's necessary.

Comment: Should it be `if idx[i] in range…`?

Comment: @AmaroVita Thank you, I thought of that and posted the answer, anyway you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is these line:

```
i = i - 1
i = i + 1
```

You're essentially always looping through `i = 1`, so the first condition `i in range(1, 10)` will always fire and give you 5 zeroes padding.

As the other users have mentioned you should just pad the zeroes in the string instead of the multiple conditions.

```
delist.append("ladybug_cube_{:06}_0.jpg".format(idx[i]))
```

Better yet, there's no point in having both `i` and `idx` since the index is irrelevant (it's the equivalent of the values).  You can just have `idx = list(range(100000))` and loop through `idx` instead of doing all these index managing, like so:

```
idx = list(range(100000))
for i in idx:
    delist.append("ladybug_cube_{:06}_0.jpg".format(i))
```

You might even further simplify your code to this list comprehension:

```
delist = ["ladybug_cube_{:06}_0.jpg".format(i) for i in range(100000)]
```

Output:

```
['ladybug_cube_000000_0.jpg',
 'ladybug_cube_000001_0.jpg',
 ...
 'ladybug_cube_000010_0.jpg',
 'ladybug_cube_000011_0.jpg',
 'ladybug_cube_000012_0.jpg',
 ...
 'ladybug_cube_000100_0.jpg',
 'ladybug_cube_000101_0.jpg',
 'ladybug_cube_000102_0.jpg',
 ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the conditions from:

```
if/elif i in range(x,y):
```

to

```
if/elif int(idx[i]) in range(x,y):
```

since it was using i counter instead of the real value idx[i] that it required to properly work.

Answer (score 0):

Your script confuses me, but if I am not mistaken, this replicates your script:

```
idx = [0, 1, 2, 14, 121, 123100]
delist = ["ladybug_cube_" + str(i).zfill(6) + "_0.jpg" for i in idx]

#output
['ladybug_cube_000000_0.jpg', 'ladybug_cube_000001_0.jpg', 'ladybug_cube_000002_0.jpg', 'ladybug_cube_000014_0.jpg', 'ladybug_cube_000121_0.jpg', 'ladybug_cube_123100_0.jpg']
```