# Keep zero digit save while converting string to integer in python

Tags: python, string, int, string-conversion

I am converting a string into integer using int function and it is working fine but i want to keep save zero digit that are at the start of the string.

```
string_value = '0123'
print(int(string_value))
result is 123
```

How can i format output 0123 as in integer type value not in string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nicest way to pad zeroes to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string)

Comment: you want to result be `0123` and have an `int` type? it is not possible

Answer (score 2):

You can't, but if you want to put 0's (zero padding) at the beginning of your number, this is the way to do it.

```
"{:04}".format(123)
# '0123'

"{:05}".format(123)
# '00123'
```

Comment: The result type is string i want integer type.

Comment: @SheikhJames As everyone here pointed out, it's not possible. You need to change your way of thinking or the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Like every one said you can try above answers or the following :

```
string_value = '0123'
int_no = int(string_value)

print("%04d" % int_no)

print(string_value.zfill(4))
```

Both will give same answer

Comment: Print result type is string i want integer type.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible, you cannot get an integer value of `0123`.

You should change your mind, you do not actually need `0123` in integer, but you need to keep zero when displaying it. So the question should change to how to format output.