# Append string at the beginning

Tags: python, string, pandas, append

I have a pandas Series of strings and I want to append this strings at the beginning of it with zeros.

for example I have this `123456` and I want to have this `00000123456`.
Not all the strings are equal size(length) and each string's size must be 11.

I tried this code:

```
x = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == df['ID'].str.len():
        df['ID'].join((11-i)*'0')
```

and getting this error:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nicest way to pad zeroes to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, use `str` on your column and then `zfill`. Small example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['123456', '234567', '345678'], columns=['ID'])
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.zfill(11)
```

Gives you:

```
             ID
0   00000123456
1   00000234567
2   00000345678
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.zfill`

**Ex:**

```
n = "123456"
print(n.zfill(11))
```

**Output:**

```
00000123456
```