# Change formatting of bin using OOP in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, bin

I've encountered a question on a course in oop in python regarding bin().
The author wanted to modify it in such a way that it would return the binary representation of a number in a different format.

For example, bin(30), instead of '0b11110' would output '00011110'. This can be done, for instance, by a workaround

```
bin(30)[2:].zfill(8)
```

According to the [documentary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) and [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-string), this can be done also by

```
f'{30:08b}'
```

Is there a smart way to define a class to do just that? Note, a beginner here. Here's my attempt:

```
class my_bin(object):
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.binary = format(value, '08b')

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.binary)
```

Comment: Why write a class? `bin` is a function, just write another function that implements the workaround.

Comment: No, why would you need to use class? You are not keeping state. You can trivially create a function instead: `my_bin = lambda v: f'{v:08b}'` and know it'll always return a string.

Comment: it's just a question from a user of an online course. I agree, a function should be enough.

Comment: for a class you can write your own __format__ method - so that would allow you to write your own formatting syntax for your binary values : 
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization