# How to generate roll numbers in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['abc1@abc.com','abc2@abc.com','abc3@abc.com','abc4@abc.com','abc2@abc.com','abc3@abc.com'],
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   })
```

I need to generate rollnumber for column A in the format

**"string+!--10digitnumberstaringfrom1--+string"**

**If the values are repeated roll number should be unique.**

**Expected Output:**

```
              A     B  RollNumber
0   abc1@abc.com    4  ABC000000001AB
1   abc2@abc.com    5  ABC000000002AB
2   abc3@abc.com    4  ABC000000003AB
3   abc4@abc.com    5  ABC000000004AB
4   abc2@abc.com    5  ABC000000002AB
5   abc3@abc.com    4  ABC000000003AB
```

Comment: Can you add expected output and code, what you try?

Comment: @jezrael check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with [zero fill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339013):

```
#python 3.6+
df['RollNumber'] = [f'ABC{x:010}AB' for x in range(1, len(df) + 1)]
#python 3
#df['RollNumber'] = ['ABC{0:010d}AB'.format(x) for x in range(1, len(df) + 1)]
print (df)

              A  B       RollNumber
0  abc1@abc.com  4  ABC0000000001AB
1  abc2@abc.com  5  ABC0000000002AB
2  abc3@abc.com  4  ABC0000000003AB
3  abc4@abc.com  5  ABC0000000004AB
4   abc2@bc.com  5  ABC0000000005AB
5   abc3@bc.com  4  ABC0000000006AB
```

EDIT: For same values per column `A` need [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) with [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
s = pd.Series(pd.factorize(df['A'])[0] + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(10)
df['RollNumber'] = ('ABC' + s + 'AB')
print (df)
              A  B       RollNumber
0  abc1@abc.com  4  ABC0000000001AB
1  abc2@abc.com  5  ABC0000000002AB
2  abc3@abc.com  4  ABC0000000003AB
3  abc4@abc.com  5  ABC0000000004AB
4  abc2@abc.com  5  ABC0000000002AB
5  abc3@abc.com  4  ABC0000000003AB
```

Comment: @what if I have repeated values check the  expected output now

Comment: how to use df['RollNumber'] = [f'ABC{x:010}AB' for x in range(1, len(df) + 1)] this code to print from start roll number from 20

Comment: @Yog - Use `df['RollNumber'] = [f'ABC{x:010}AB' for x in range(20, len(df) + 21)]`

Comment: geeting this error ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: @Yog - ooops, not tested -  need `df['RollNumber'] = [f'ABC{x:010}AB' for x in range(20, len(df) + 20)] `

Comment: what if df['A'] is not in ascending order ? like `[abc1,abc2,abc4,abc2]`