# Join a list of numbers into a string, maintain overall spacing between elements and characters

Tags: python, string, list, join, plot

I am working with a list of numbers, where each single digit number has been formatted to have 2 characters, i.e. ' 9', '20',  ' 1' and etc.

My issue is when I turn the list into a string, via str.join, the new string keeps the spacing correct when I print, but for plotting it doesn't. I could just add a leading zero to keep the integrity, but for aesthetic purposes I want to keep single digit numbers.

I have 2 of these lists that have been converted to strings, with different numbers, so when they vary, they start to stray from one another. Is it possible to keep the spacing integrity like print does, for plotting text.

The text prints like this (spacing perfect, same width):

```
 1  3  4  2  2  4  4  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  6 14 11 16 16 10  5  4  3  3  6

 2  4  4  4  3  5  5  3  1  2  1  1  1  3 14 18 13 21 20 12 10  6  4  4  8
```

But plots like this (where the overall spacing and width is off).

1  3  4  2  2  4  4  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  6 14 11 16 16 10  5  4  3  3  6

2  4  4  4  3  5  5  3  1  2  1  1  1  3 14 18 13 21 20 12 10  6  4  4  8

I am aware of using spacing between characters in join, but here is some of my code:

```
q = [1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 14, 11, 16, 16, 10, 5, 4, 3, 3, 6]

q1 = [2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 14, 18, 13, 21, 20, 12, 10, 6, 4, 4, 8]

ddd = ['{:2}'.format(x) for x in q]
dddd = ['{:2}'.format(x) for x in q1]


q3 = " ".join(['{:>2}'.format(x) for x in ddd])
q4 = " ".join(['{:>2}'.format(x) for x in dddd])
```

Pic for reference

[image]

Plotting text code:

```
ax.text(0.035, 0.97, q3, horizontalalignment='left',
    verticalalignment='baseline', fontsize=9.5, transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.text(0.035, 0.92, q4, horizontalalignment='left',
        verticalalignment='baseline', fontsize=9.5, transform=ax.transAxes)
```

Comment: What do you mean by plotting text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nicest way to pad zeroes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-a-string)

Comment: plotting text with plt.text over a graph. i've added a pic to help

Comment: I've looked into padding with zeroes. It makes it even, but I don't want leading zeroes.

Comment: @user279955 Can you show us the code you use to make the plot (or at least the code which adds the text to the plot) ?

Comment: added plotting code for text