# Display leading zero from list

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to generate 3 digits numbers randomly. But I can't find how to display leading zero after the range function.

I tried on Jupyter notebook with python3 version.

```
    import random
    raw_list = list(range(000,999))
    print ("Original list : ",  raw_list)
    random.shuffle(raw_list) #shuffle method
    print ("List after first shuffle  : ",  raw_list)
```

I only get numbers like that -

```
List after first shuffle  :  [474, 421, 46, 183,.....................
```

The final output to I would like to generate is
[000,111,002,...098............,999]

Comment: go and have a look at [Nicest way to pad zeroes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/nicest-way-to-pad-zeroes-to-a-string)

Comment: You should use strings of length 3. Checkout the solution by @Kvothe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in int you lose always the leading 0. You could switch to str and add the leading zeros for example like that:

```
def add_zeros(z):
    while len(z) < 3:
        z = '0' + z
    return z

new_list = [add_zeros(str(z)) for z in raw_list]
print ("List after first shuffle  : ",  new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

raw_list = list(range(000, 999))
n_raw_list=[str(num).zfill(3) for num in raw_list]
print("Original list : ", n_raw_list)
random.shuffle(n_raw_list)  # shuffle method
print("List after first shuffle  : ", n_raw_list)
```

Try this hopefully this will work

Comment: I am glad to help you out with your problem. MP