# how start loop from three number in python?

Tags: python

How to start the iteration loop from 000 to 999 using while loop in python?

```
x1=0
x2=999

while x1 <= x2:
    print (x1)
    x1 += 1
```

don't use for loop, just while loop

Comment: This code works fine

Comment: Code works without any issue.
Did you test it?

Comment: What's the problem here? The code is correct.

Comment: Perhaps your real question is how to pad numbers less than 100 by zeros when printing them so that e.g. 57 displays as 057?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/how-to-pad-zeroes-to-a-string

Comment: Is the problem that you want it to print '000' and not '0' and so on?

Comment: You need something like this:

 while x1 <= x2:
...     print (f'{x1:03}')
...     x1 += 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
In [1538]: x1=0 
      ...: x2=999
      ...:  
      ...: while x1 <= x2: 
      ...:     print (str(x1).zfill(3)) 
      ...:     x1 += 1 
      ...:
```

Prints something like this:

```
000
001
002
003
004
005
006
007
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to pad the number with zeros,

```
print(f'{x1:03}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
while x1 <= x2:
     print (f'{x1:03}')
     x1 += 1
```