# How can I fix SyntaxError: invalid syntax when trying to pad zeros to a numeric string?

Tags: python, string, if-statement, zero-padding

```
for i in range(1,50): 
    path = if i < 10:
               url + '0' + str(i)
           else:
               url + str(i)

    df = pd.read_html(path)
```

in this situation, I got

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax for 'if'.
```

how can I fix this code?

Comment: The `if` statement in Python is not an expression and does not have a value. It cannot be assigned to a variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pad zeroes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/how-to-pad-zeroes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and explicit and just do:

```
if i < 10:
    path =   url + '0' + str(i)
else:
    path =  url + str(i)
```

Or, use Python's [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) capabilities to create your string. If you want a zero-padded string with a minimal length of 2 characters, you can use the following format:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> f'{a:0>2}'
'03'
>>> a = 33
>>> f'{a:0>2}'
'33'
>>> a = 333
>>> f'{a:0>2}'
'333'
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to "reformat" the path, converting *i* to a zero-padded string.
So the most natural way is to use just the zero-padded formatting, accessible
among others in *f_strings*. Something like:

```
for i in range(1,50):
    path = url + f'{i:02}'
    # Do with your path whatever you wish
```

Comment: Rather, `path = f'{url}{i:02}'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use if statement in assignment you can do the following:

```
path = url + '0' + str(i) if i < 10 else url + str(i)
```

thus your code inside the loop will be like the following:

```py
for i in range(1,50):
    path = url + '0' + str(i) if i < 10 else url + str(i)
    df = pd.read_html(path)
    ...
```

There is an another approach for your goal. You need to zero pad the number to make it 2 characters, so you can use `zfill` method of str class.

```py
for i in range(1,50):
    padded_i = str(i).zfill(2)
    path = '{url}{id}'.format(url=url, id=padded_i)
    df = pd.read_html(path)
    ...
```

You can use traditional way as well but it's not sweet as the previous ones:

```py
for i in range(1, 50):
    if i < 10:
        i = '0' + str(i)
    else:
        i = str(i)

    path = url + i
    df = pd.read_html(path)
        ...
```