# Convert string hours to minute pd.eval

Tags: python, pandas, time, timedelta

I want to convert all rows of my DataFrame that contains hours and minutes into minutes only.
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df=
    time
0    8h30
1    14h07
2    08h30
3    7h50
4    8h0 
5    8h15
6    6h15
```

I'm using the following method to convert:

```
df['time'] = pd.eval(
    df['time'].replace(['h'], ['*60+'], regex=True))
```

Output

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think the error comes from the format of the hour, maybe `pd.eval`cant accept `08h30` or `8h0`, how to solve this probleme ?

Comment: The regex replace produces strings like `08*60+30`, whose leading zeros cause syntax errors in `pd.eval`. Would you be open to splitting the col on `'h'` and converting strings to `int`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63026713/leading-zeros-are-not-allowed-in-python

Comment: It's seem to be a good idea indeed, but the problem is that I have a large dataset with many feature like this and I expected a faster method

Comment: The strings are incomplete because it only contains the hours. If it included `m` at the end, you could easily let Pandas parse them into `timedelta64`. `pd.to_timedelta('14h07m')` works. You could use `pd.to_timedelta(d1['time'])`

Comment: I posted an answer that shows how to handle those strings as timedeltas with (almost) no string manipulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having to trim leading zeros, an alternative approach:

```
df[['h', 'm']] = df['time'].str.split('h', expand=True).astype(int)
df['total_min'] = df['h']*60 + df['m']
```

Result:

```
    time   h   m      total_min
0   8h30   8  30            510
1  14h07  14   7            847
2  08h30   8  30            510
3   7h50   7  50            470
4    8h0   8   0            480
5   8h15   8  15            495
6   6h15   6  15            375
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas can already handle such strings if the units are included in the string. While `14h07` can't be parse (why assume `07` is minutes?), `14h07` can be converted to a [Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timedeltas.html) :

```
>>> pd.to_timedelta("14h07m")
Timedelta('0 days 14:07:00')
```

Given this dataframe :

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(['8h30m', '14h07m', '08h30m', '8h0m'],
                  columns=['time'])
```

You can convert the `time` series into a Timedelta series with `pd.to_timedelta` :

```
>>> d1['tm'] = pd.to_timedelta(d1['time'])
>>> d1
     time              tm
0   8h30m 0 days 08:30:00
1  14h07m 0 days 14:07:00
2  08h30m 0 days 08:30:00
3    8h0m 0 days 08:00:00
```

To handle the missing minutes unit in the original data, just append `m`:

```
d1['tm'] = pd.to_timedelta(d1['time'] + 'm')
```

Once you have a `Timedelta` you can calculate hours and minutes.

The components of the values can be retrieved with [Timedelta.components](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.components.html)

```
>>> d1.tm.dt.components.hours
0     8
1    14
2     8
3     8
Name: hours, dtype: int64
```

To get the total minutes, seconds or hours, change the frequency to minutes:

```
>>> d1.tm.astype('timedelta64[m]')
0    510.0
1    847.0
2    510.0
3    480.0
Name: tm, dtype: float64
```

Bringing all the operations together :

```
>>> d1['tm'] = pd.to_timedelta(d1['time'])
>>> d2 = (d1.assign(h=d1.tm.dt.components.hours,
...                 m=d1.tm.dt.components.minutes,
...                 total_minutes=d1.tm.astype('timedelta64[m]')))
>>>
>>> d2
     time              tm   h   m  total_minutes
0   8h30m 0 days 08:30:00   8  30          510.0
1  14h07m 0 days 14:07:00  14   7          847.0
2  08h30m 0 days 08:30:00   8  30          510.0
3    8h0m 0 days 08:00:00   8   0          480.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give an alternative approach with kind of the same elements as above you could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["8h30", "14h07", "08h30", "7h50", "8h0 ", "8h15", "6h15"],
                  columns=["time"])
```

First split you column on the "h"

```
hm = df["time"].str.split("h", expand=True)
```

Then combine the columns again, but zeropad time hours and minutes in order to make valid time strings:

```
df2 = hm[0].str.strip().str.zfill(2) + hm[1].str.strip().str.zfill(2)
```

Then convert the string column with proper values to a date time column:

```
df3 = pd.to_datetime(df2, format="%H%M")
```

Finally, calculate the number of minutes by subtrackting a zero time (to make deltatimes) and divide by the minutes deltatime:

```
zerotime= pd.to_datetime("0000", format="%H%M")
df['minutes'] = (df3 - zerotime) / pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
```

The results look like:

```
    time  minutes
0   8h30    510.0
1  14h07    847.0
2  08h30    510.0
3   7h50    470.0
4   8h0     480.0
5   8h15    495.0
6   6h15    375.0
```