# How to convert a three digit integer (xxx) with a 1 decimal place float (xx.x)?

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error

Currently I'm getting data from some sensors with voltage(V) and current(C) values which is decoded into text as `V040038038039C125067` to be stored in MYSQL DB table. The voltage contains 4 different voltage values combined while the current contains 2 different current values combined where each value represented by 3 digits in the format of `Voltage xx.x C: Current xx.x`. For example, the current value of C125067 is actually 12.5 and 06.7A respectively. I tried to use python slicing some and some simple math to achieve this by dividing the values by 10 e.g. C125067 = 125/10 = 12.5. While this works for integers with first non-zero values (e.g. 125), when I tried to perform the same for values such as 040 or 067, I get the *SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted* error. Are there any better ways to achieve the desired decoding output of xx.x or to insert a decimal point before the last digit etc? Thanks.

```
v1 = voltage[1:4]
v2 = voltage[4:7]
v3 = voltage[7:10]
v4 = voltage[10:13]
c1 = current[1:4]
c2 = current[4:7]

volt_1 = int(v1)/10
volt_2 = int(v2)/10
volt_3 = int(v3)/10
volt_4 = int(v4)/10

curr_1 = int(c1)/10
curr_2 = int(c2)/10
```

Comment: Share the complete stack trace. Also share what the `voltage` and `current` variables are. I'm unable to replicate the error you're facing from the information you've shared so far.

Comment: Remove the leading zeroes with the `lstrip()` method: `int(v1.lstrip('0'))`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. You only get this error if you convert numeric literal with a leading zero (e.g. `int(0123)`). When a string is used it's converted just fine: `int('0123')`. Your code as posted does not produce an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Python are you using? `int` should convert strings such as `'040'` just fine.

```
Python 3.9.13 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, May 27 2022, 16:56:21) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: int('040')
Out[1]: 40

In [2]:
```

Are you by any chance typing `int(040)` instead of `int('040')`? One is a *decimal integer literal* while the latter is a string.

[Leading zeros are not allowed in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63026713/leading-zeros-are-not-allowed-in-python)

Using python 3.9.13, your code works without problems.

```py
voltage = "V040038038039C125067"

v1 = voltage[1:4]
v2 = voltage[4:7]
v3 = voltage[7:10]
v4 = voltage[10:13]

volt_1 = int(v1)/10
volt_2 = int(v2)/10
volt_3 = int(v3)/10
volt_4 = int(v4)/10

print(v1, v2, v3, v4, volt_1, volt_2, volt_3, volt_4)
# 040 038 038 039 4.0 3.8 3.8 3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to get a list of 6 string values from your sql data (grouped by 3 digits).

The most efficient way to use the regex is to compile it at the beginning then use the compiled regex on your sql rows.

Use a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to obtain a list of floats (converted from strings, also stripping the leading zeros).

Use [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=sequence%20unpacking#tuples-and-sequences) to separate into a voltage list and a current list.

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\d{3})")
data = "V040038038039C125067"
values = [int(x.lstrip("0")) / 10.0 for x  in pattern.findall(data)]
voltage, current = values[:4], values[4:]
print(voltage, current)  # [4.0, 3.8, 3.8, 3.9] [12.5, 6.7]
```

You can make a function of that, to easily apply to your sql rows.

```py
def parse(data):
    values = [int(x.lstrip("0")) / 10.0 for x  in pattern.findall(data)]
    return values[:4], values[4:]

voltage, current = parse("V040038038039C125067")
```

Answer (score -2):

**This is a Very Simple Problem**
What you have to do is just divide the number by 10 and convert it into float with float inbuilt function in python.

```
a = int(input("Enter a random number: "))
print(float(a/10))
```

now apply it in your problem.

```
volt_1 = float(int(v1)/10)
volt_2 = float(int(v2)/10)
volt_3 = float(int(v3)/10)
volt_4 = float(int(v4)/10)

curr_1 = float(int(c1)/10)
curr_2 = float(int(c2)/10)
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issues in the question at all.

Comment: Now it is right. i added it by mistake. If you have any suggetion to improve this answer please tell me.