# How to restrict the number of digits in an fstring in Python

Tags: python, f-string

I would like to use an f-string in Python to generate the following folders:

```
folder01
folder02
folder03
folder04
folder05
folder06
folder07
folder08
folder09
folder10
folder11
```

I currently have the following code, which obviously doesn't do what I want, but how can I change it so that it does?

`folders = [f"folder0{i}" for i in range(0,12)]`

This generates:

```
folder01
folder02
folder03
folder04
folder05
folder06
folder07
folder08
folder09
folder010
folder011
```

Notice the extra 0 with folder010 and folder011

Comment: @IainShelvington it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in simple way

```
folders = [f"Folder{i:0=2d}" for i in range(1,12)]

print(folders)
```

**Output**

```
['Folder01', 'Folder02', 'Folder03', 'Folder04', 'Folder05', 'Folder06', 'Folder07', 'Folder08', 'Folder09', 'Folder10', 'Folder11']
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken the hint [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/339013/13669871):

```
[f"folder{i:02}" for i in range(1,12)]

['folder01',
 'folder02',
 'folder03',
 'folder04',
 'folder05',
 'folder06',
 'folder07',
 'folder08',
 'folder09',
 'folder10',
 'folder11']
```