# Creating URLs in a loop

Tags: python, for-loop, url, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to create a list of URLs using a for loop. It prints all the correct URLs, but is not saving them in a list. Ultimately I want to download multiple files using [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve).

```
for i, j in zip(range(0, 17), range(1, 18)):
    if i < 8 or j < 10:
        url = "https://Here is a URL/P200{}".format(i) + "-0{}".format(j) + ".xls"
        print(url)
    if i == 9 and j == 10:
        url = "https://Here is a URL/P200{}".format(i) + "-{}".format(j) + ".xls"
        print(url)
    if i > 9:
        if i > 9 or j < 8:
            url = "https://Here is a URL/P20{}".format(i) + "-{}".format(j) + ".xls"
            print(url)
```

Output of above code is:

```
https://Here is a URL/P2000-01.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2001-02.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2002-03.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2003-04.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2004-05.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2005-06.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2006-07.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2007-08.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2008-09.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2009-10.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2010-11.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2011-12.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2012-13.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2013-14.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2014-15.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2015-16.xls
https://Here is a URL/P2016-17.xls
```

But this:

```
url
```

gives only:

```
'https://Here is a URL/P2016-17.xls'
```

How do I get all the URLs, not just the final one?

Comment: What happens when you, say, try to save the URLs in a list?

Comment: you are replacing url variable everytime with new value. If you want to preserve values, you need to create a list and assign values to the list

Comment: The Final url is overwriting all the urls

Comment: @sunilbaba I have been trying to downlaod the data. Till now the website has data till 2016-17 but when the data for 2017-18 also comes the URL list will not be able to collect the the data automatically, Goal is to automate the script so as to reduce the manual effort

Comment: If you reduce your range, you will restrict your URL formation till 2016-17 itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that could significantly simplify your code. First of all, this:

```py
"https://Here is a URL/P200{}".format(i) + "-0{}".format(j) + ".xls"
```

could be simplified to this:

```py
"https://Here is a URL/P200{}-0{}.xls".format(i, j)
```

And if you have at least Python 3.6, you could use an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) instead:

```py
f"https://Here is a URL/P200{i}-0{j}.xls"
```

Second of all, Python has several ways to conveniently pad numbers with zeroes; it can even be done [as part of the f-string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24386708/12975140). Additionally, [`range`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) starts from zero by default.

So your entire original code is equivalent to:

```py
for num in range(17):
    print(f'https://Here is a URL/P20{num:02}-{num+1:02}.xls')
```

Now, you want to actually use these URLs, not just print them out. You mentioned building a list, which can be done like so:

```py
urls = []
for num in range(17):
    urls.append(f'https://Here is a URL/P20{num:02}-{num+1:02}.xls')
```

Or with a [list comprehension](https://realpython.com/courses/understand-list-comprehensions/):

```py
urls = [f'https://Here is a URL/P20{num:02}-{num+1:02}.xls'
        for num in range(17)]
```

---

Based on your comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843258/creating-urls-in-a-loop/65851622#comment116416414_65843392) and on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847171/convert-list-of-string-into-list-of-url-using-python#comment116444109_65847171), you seem to be confused about what form you need these URLs to be in. Strings like this are *already what you need*. [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) accepts the URL *as a string*, so you don't need to do any further processing. See the example in the docs:

> ```py
> local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://python.org/')
> html = open(local_filename)
> html.close()
> ```

**However, I would recommend not using `urlretrieve`, for two reasons.**

1. As the documentation mentions, `urlretrieve` is a legacy method that may become deprecated. If you're going to use `urllib`, use the [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) method instead.
2. However, as Paul Becotte mentioned in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65847374/12975140) to your other question: if you're looking to fetch URLs, I would recommend [installing](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install/#install) and using [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) instead of `urllib`. It's more user-friendly.

Regardless of which method you choose, again, *strings are fine*. Here's code that that uses Requests to download each of the specified spreadsheets to your current directory:

```py
import requests

base_url = 'https://Here is a URL/'

for num in range(17):
    filename = f'P20{num:02}-{num+1:02}.xls'
    xls = requests.get(base_url + filename)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(xls.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the results of the URL with final URL. you need to maintain a final list and keep adding new values to the list

```
import urllib.parse
url=[];
for i,j in zip(range(0,17),range(1,18)):
    if(i<8 or j<10):
        url.append("https://Here is a URL/P200{}".format(i)+"-0{}".format(j)+".xls")
    if(i==9 and  j==10):
        url.append("https://Here is a URL/P200{}".format(i)+"-{}".format(j)+".xls") 
    if(i>9):
        if((i>9) or (j<8)):
            url.append("https://Here is a URL/P20{}".format(i)+"-{}".format(j)+".xls")

for urlValue in url:
            print(urllib.parse.quote(urlValue))
```

Comment: Thanks it did create a list but did not remain in link form therefore can not be used to download

Comment: you can use urllib to convert string value back to URL format. 
import urllib
urllib.quote(<ListValue>)

Comment: I have tried urllib.quote(url), urllib.parse.quote(url), urllib.parse.urlencoder(url),,, all three of them not working!