# Convert list of String into list of URL using Python

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

I Have a list of string(which are actually URL)

```
['https://part.of.url/P2000-01.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2001-02.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2002-03.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2003-04.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2004-05.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2005-06.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2006-07.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2007-08.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2008-09.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2009-10.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2010-11.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2011-12.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2012-13.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2013-14.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2014-15.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2015-16.xls',

 'https://part.of.url/P2016-17.xls']
```

I wish to convert it into link form and using the code

```
    for urlValue in url:
        print(urllib.parse.quote(urlValue))
```

output I am getting is

```
https%3A//part.of.url/P2012-13.xls

https%3A//part.of.url/P2013-14.xls

https%3A//part.of.url/P2014-15.xls

https%3A//part.of.url/P2015-16.xls
```

It should be the list of URL containing list such as below.

https://part.of.url/P2012-13.xls

How can it be solved?

Comment: aren't they already valid urls?

Comment: no they are not valid

Comment: can you describe what exactly output you want to get

Comment: @Sneha explain how `https://part.of.url/P2012-13.xls`, which you claim is an element of your list, is not a valid url.

Comment: @Abhishek Bharti a valid url (https://part.of.url/P2012-13.xls) will have a colon after https inplace of %3A (https%3A//part.of.url/P2012-13.xls)

Comment: What Chase is saying is that your original list, *before* processing, already consists of valid URLs. Why are you even trying to change it?

Comment: @crazyChucky thanks for explaining. @ chase its in string form which can not be read

Comment: ...Cannot be read by what? What do you want them to be, if not strings? That's how you store text in Python.

Comment: @Sneha We're not sure about what you want to do with the urls. Do you want to fetch the excel files in the urls? Do you want to validate the urls? Your problem is easier to solve if your intent is clear

Comment: Based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65843258/creating-a-loop-for-urls-in-python/65851622), it looks like you plan to supply these to [`urllib.request.urlretreive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve). If so, strings are fine.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Yes

Comment: @Jakob Lindskog Intent is to have URL (where you click the url and directly reaches to website) and then use urllib.request.urlretreive to downlaod the files in the programme.

Comment: That's not how it works. For `urllib.request.urlretrieve`, *you want a string*. There's no "clicking" to be done. What you have already is fine. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65851622/12975140) to your previous question for a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"quote" is the wrong method for this. It is used specifically to remove special characters from a string, which is what you are seeing.

If you are trying to build url objects, urllib.parse.urlparse(urlValue) would be the method you want.

As someone new to python- the urllib libraries are pretty low API. Assuming you're trying to make network connections, I would strongly recommend looking at the "requests" library from pypi, which is a much simpler user interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to quote. It should work with the following code. If not then please clarify and share your full source.

```
    for urlValue in url:
        print(urlValue)
```

Comment: @Mehedi, thanks but the output is not giving a list but the last url is overriding all other urls

Comment: Please share your full source code and python version.

Comment: Python Version is 3. Codes are already shared.