# Ascend 000 to 999

Tags: python

I am trying to repeatedly ascend integers in the format of `000`, `001`, I have attempted to do the following

```
>>> for x in range(000, 999):
        ...
```

**BUT**, it returns..

```
1
2
3
4...
```

Comment: What return type do you need at the end of all of these operations because leading zeros are not allowed for decimal numbers

Comment: Leading zeros is not a thing in `python` `integer` type. But `string` formatting is what you're looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pad zeroes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/how-to-pad-zeroes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
for i in range(0, 1000):
    print(f"{i:03}")
```

Addendum: If you simply want to print it, you need to convert it to string. You cannot have `001` in an integer format.

Edit: change the range to end at 1000, if you want to print 999.