# How to pad a zero input in an argparser default?

Tags: python

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
day_before_date1 = datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=2)
day_before_date = day_before_date1.strftime("%d")
print(day_before_date)  # 01 (is the output)
```

I have to use arg parser in python to take input for day. If I don't give any input it defaults to `presentdate-2`, which is 01.

```
parser.add_argument('number',type=int, help="Number represents date" , nargs='?' , default=day_before_date , const="num")
```

I have set `default=int(day_before_date)` but it still registers the input as `1` and not `01` when I `print(args.number)`
I need `01` when i `print(args.number)`.

Comment: You could use an f-string to print the value: `print(f"{day_before_data:02}")`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pad zeroes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339007/how-to-pad-zeroes-to-a-string)

Comment: You have `type=int` in `parser.add_argument`. "01" is a string.

Comment: @Macattack ,No 
So when i will have days like 11 , 12 , it will add 0 to it as well and make it 011 , 012

Comment: similar to the f string you could use just the `%` formatting: `"%02d" % 2" -> 02`

Comment: The `zfill` method can be used as `'1'.zfill(2)` —> `'01'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.rjust` method, this will guarantee that you will only ever have 2 characters so if it is `11` it will output `'11'` but if it is `3` it will output `'03'`

```
>>> a = 1
>>> str(a).rjust(2,"0")
"01"
```

another method is to use inline formating with f-strings.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = f"{a:02d}"
>>> b
"01"
```

Or you can use conditional statement (not recommended).

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = '0' + str(a) if len(str(a)) == 1 else str(a)
>>> b
'01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. The first is to change what type your argument is in argparser:

```
parser.add_argument('number',type=str, help="Number represents date" , nargs='?' , default="01", const="num")
...
day_number_arg = int(args.number)
... # use `day_number_arg` wherever you would have used `args.number`
print(args.number)  # will print '01' if the default is used.
```

Here you take in a string and convert it to a number. You can print out the original argument as the string passed in, or the default.

Elsewise you can take your calculated value and use a format string:

```
day_number = 1
f"{day_number:02d}"
```

This says 'print two digits of `day_number`'. In this manner you can format the output, meaning you can use whatever your final value is. In general this would be the recommend method.

Comment: ```
parser.add_argument('number',type=str, help="Number represents date" , nargs='?' , default="01", const="num")
...
day_number_arg = int(args.number)
... # use `day_number_arg` wherever you would have used `args.number`
print(args.number)

```
This gives 1 not ```01```